# The GridView 'SPGridView1' fired event PageIndexChanging which wasn't handled

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, gridview

I have the following code to bind a gridview to a specific data source with paging included, but when I click on the next page I get the error:

The GridView 'SPGridView1' fired event PageIndexChanging which wasn't handled.

The code is as follows:

```
namespace AuditingLog.AuditLogViewerWebPart
{
    public partial class AuditLogViewerWebPartUserControl : UserControl
    {
        protected string PageTitle;
        protected string PageTitleInArea;
        protected string PageDescription;

        private SPList _HistorialIngresos;
        public SPListItemCollection _lstRecords;
        private SPWeb web;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // only show delete button to site collection owner
            cmdDeleteAllEntries.Visible = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.IsSiteAdmin;
            tableButtons.Visible = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.IsSiteAdmin;

            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                SetupWebpart();
                SetupGrid();
                BindGridToDataSource();
                //GetDataFromDataSource();
            }
        }

        private void BindGridToDataSource()
        {
            SPGridView1.DataSource = GetDataFromDataSource();
            SPGridView1.DataBind();
        }

        private void SetupGrid()
        {
            SPBoundField boundField = new SPBoundField();
            boundField.HeaderText = "User";
            boundField.DataField = "User";
            SPGridView1.Columns.Add(boundField);

            boundField = new SPBoundField();
            boundField.HeaderText = "Event";
            boundField.DataField = "Event";
            SPGridView1.Columns.Add(boundField);

            boundField = new SPBoundField();
            boundField.HeaderText = "ItemType";
            boundField.DataField = "ItemType";
            SPGridView1.Columns.Add(boundField);

            boundField = new SPBoundField();
            boundField.HeaderText = "DocLocation";
            boundField.DataField = "DocLocation";
            SPGridView1.Columns.Add(boundField);

            boundField = new SPBoundField();
            boundField.HeaderText = "Occurred";
            boundField.DataField = "Occurred";
            boundField.ControlStyle.Width = new Unit(120);
            SPGridView1.Columns.Add(boundField);


            SPGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            //SPGridView1.DataSource = GetDataFromDataSource();
            // Turn on paging and add event handler
            SPGridView1.PageSize = 3;
            SPGridView1.AllowPaging = true;
            SPGridView1.PageIndexChanging +=
                new GridViewPageEventHandler(SPGridView1_PageIndexChanging);
            SPGridView1.PagerTemplate = null;  // Must be called after Controls.Add(oGrid)

            //SPGridView1.DataBind();

            SPGridView1.AllowSorting = true;
            SPGridView1.HeaderStyle.Font.Bold = true;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get data from Sharepoint Audit Query API
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private DataTable GetDataFromDataSource()
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();                     
            // read audit log
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                using (SPSite siteColl = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.ID))
                {
                    using (SPWeb site = siteColl.OpenWeb(SPContext.Current.Web.ID))
                    {
                        SPAuditQuery wssQuery = new SPAuditQuery(siteColl);
                        SPAuditEntryCollection auditCol = siteColl.Audit.GetEntries(wssQuery);
                        table.Columns.Add("User", typeof(string));
                        table.Columns.Add("Event", typeof(string));
                        table.Columns.Add("ItemType", typeof(string));
                        table.Columns.Add("DocLocation", typeof(string));
                        table.Columns.Add("Occurred", typeof(DateTime));
                        DataRow newRow;

                        foreach (SPAuditEntry entry in auditCol)
                        {
                            newRow = table.Rows.Add();
                            newRow["User"] = GetUserNameById(entry.UserId, site);
                            newRow["Event"] = entry.Event;
                            newRow["ItemType"] = entry.ItemType.ToString();
                            newRow["DocLocation"] = entry.DocLocation;
                            newRow["Occurred"] = entry.Occurred.ToLocalTime();
                        }                    

                    }
                }
            });

            return table;
        }

        void SPGridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
        {
            SPGridView1.DataSource = GetDataFromDataSource();
            SPGridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            SPGridView1.DataBind();
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Incializacion de controles
        /// </summary>
        protected void SetupWebpart()
        {
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                using (var site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.ID))
                {
                    web = site.AllWebs["/intranet"];
                    _HistorialIngresos = web.Lists["HistorialIngresos"];

                }
            });
        }



        string GetUserNameById(int UserId, SPWeb site)
        {
            if (UserId == -1)
            {
                return @"SHAREPOINT\System";
            }
            else
            {
                return site.AllUsers.GetByID(UserId).Name;
            }

        }

        protected void cmdDeleteAllEntries_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SPSite siteColl = SPContext.Current.Site;
            siteColl.Audit.DeleteEntries(DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime().AddDays(1));
            siteColl.Audit.Update();
            Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
        }

        protected void cmdRefreshPage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
        }


    }
}
```

aspx code

```
<%@ Assembly Name="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="asp" Namespace="System.Web.UI" Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="AuditLogViewerWebPartUserControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="AuditingLog.AuditLogViewerWebPart.AuditLogViewerWebPartUserControl" %>

<asp:Panel ID="paBotones" runat="server" Width="100%">
<style type="text/css">
    h2
    {
        margin: 29px 0 10px 0 !important;
    }
    .80041300-55c7-4b95-891a-e065a9b72a97 th
    {
        font-size: 15px !important;
    }
</style>
 <table runat="server" id="tableButtons" style="width:100%; background-color: #CCCCCC;" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <asp:Button ID="cmdRefreshPage" UseSubmitBehavior="false"  runat="server" Text="Refresh Page" OnClick="cmdRefreshPage_Click" Width="100px" Font-Size="8pt" />&nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="cmdDeleteAllEntries" UseSubmitBehavior="false"  runat="server" Text="Clear Audit Log" OnClick="cmdDeleteAllEntries_Click" Width="100px" Font-Size="8pt" />  
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>  
  <SharePoint:SPGridView ID="SPGridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HeaderStyle-BackColor="white" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="Transparent" Width="100%" Height="220px">
    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="ms-alternating" />
  </SharePoint:SPGridView>
  </asp:Panel>
```

Comment: show your .aspx code?

Comment: didnt think would be usefuled I just added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SPGridView1_PageIndexChanging` should be `protected` as you have `AutoEventWireup="true"`

Also remove the event subscription from your code-behind.